# SpringBoot transaction does not rollback with @EventListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jdbc

I am using SpringBoot ApplicationEvent to reduce coupling between domains.
I want that the publisher and listener should always join in the same transaction before and after @EventListener.
How it works is that domain entity registers the event and in the end of method we call a method to publishes all events registered in domain with applicationEventListener.
Why I flush before publishing events are on listener side I use jooq for fetching and I would like to avoid outdated data.
The issue is when listener side failed, only listener side transaction gets rolled back and publisher side did not rollback. Which can mean that after @EventListener the same transaction is not used.
This does not happen all the time but rarely happens.
The exceptions so far were NullPointerException, PessimisticLockException and IllegalArgumentException.
Could anyone help?

SpringBoot 2.4.4
Java 15
Dependency:
spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

```
public abstract class BaseAggregateRoot<T> {

    @Transient
    private final List<SomeEvent<T>> events = new ArrayList<>();

    protected void registerEvent(DomainEvent<T> event) {
        events.add(event);
    }

    public List<SomeEvent<T>> getEvents() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(events);
    }

    public void clearEvents() {
        events.clear();
    }
}

@Service
public class EventPublisherService {

    private final ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public <T extends BaseAggregateRoot<T>> void publishAndFlush(T aggregateRoot) {
        entityManager.flush();
        List<SomeEvent<T>> events = aggregateRoot.getEvents();
        if (!events.isEmpty()) {
            events.forEach(publisher::publishEvent);
            aggregateRoot.clearEvents();
        }
    }
}

@Entity
public class SomeEntity extends BaseAggregateRoot<SomeEntity> {

  @Column("something")
  private String something;

  public void doSomething() {
    registerEvent(new DoSomethingEvent());
  } 

}

@Service
public class Publisher {

  private final SomeRepository1 someRepository1; 
  private final EventPublisherService eventPublisherService;


  @Transactional
  public void doSomething1() {
     
     var newSomething = new SomeEntity();
      newSomething.doSomething();
     someRepository1.save(newSomething);
     eventPublisherService.publishAndFlush();
    
  }
}


@Component
public class Listener {

  private final Consumer consumer;

  @EventListener
  public void handleDoSomething1(DoSomethingEvent event) {
     consumer.doSomething2(event);
    
  }
}


@Service
public class Consumer {

  private final SomeRepository2 someRepository2; 

  @Transactional
  public void doSomething2(DoSomethingEvent event) {
 
     someRepository2.saveAndFlush();
     // something failed! (doSomething2 will be rolledback but not doSomething1)
    
  }
}
```

The configuration looks like this

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      dialect: ${hibernate.dialect}
    properties:
      hibernate:
        connection:
          provider_disables_autocommit: true
        show_sql: false
        format_sql: false
        jdbc:
          time_zone: UTC
          batch_size: 30
        generate_statistics: false


datasources:
  primary:
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    ...
    platform: mariadb
    auto-commit: false
    cachePrepStmts: true
    prepStmtCacheSize: 450
    prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
    useServerPrepStmts: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that the event listener is not wrapped with transactional proxy. So, when you invoke `consumer.doSomething2(event)` current transaction is not propagated further and Spring starts a new one. You should enable transaction logging to verify this hypothesis.

I would try to change the event listener a bit.

```
@TransactionalEventListener(phase = BEFORE_COMMIT)
@Transactional
public void handleDoSomething1(DoSomethingEvent event) {
   consumer.doSomething2(event);
}
```

Now it's guaranteed that `handleDoSomething1` is called right before committing. More than that, the transaction is propagated further `consumer.doSomething2(event)` calling.